# How to store all table in a sql database in dataframes?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am currently learning how to import data and clean it using python. I came across importing sql database and importing a table from the DB into a dataframe. Here is a sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sql_database_name.sqlite')
table = engine.table_names()
print(table)
rs = engine.execute('SELECT * from table_name')
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.fetchall())
df.columns = rs.keys()
print(df)
```

The database is stored locally. I just wanted to know if there is a way to store all the tables in the database to different dataframes or any other structure so that I won't have to execute different SQL queries for different table.

Comment: You could use a query that uses `JOIN` to combine data from different tables.

Comment: "I just wanted to know if there is a way to store all the tables in the database to different dataframes or any other structure so that I won't have to execute different SQL queries for different table." is contradictory. Yes; just make a new dataframe for each table you're querying

Comment: Write a loop, and load each table in to a different data frame.  Also look into `pandas.read_sql()` to simplify reading sql results in to a dataframe: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html